# Error with creating sql data name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to make search by name and surname , and I use this  Query(SUR - surname , NAM - name

```
Declare @name varchar(30) = 'Joh'  //part or full name/surname or both
SELECT (RTRIM(SUR) + ' ' + RTRIM(NAM)) AS name , W , SS FROM Table
WHERE name like '%' + @name + '%'
```

But I have an error

> Invalid column name "name".

I need to make search by 2 columns in same time . This

```
(SUR like '%' + @name + '%') or (NAM like '%' + @name + '%')
```

gave me search only by 1 column like : Search : Jones and I see Johnes but if i want search John Jones i will haven't result .

Help me to make search by 2 columns in same time.

Comment: You can't reference an alias like that - you'll need to either use a sub-select or replace your `WHERE name LIKE` with `WHERE (RTRIM(SUR) + ' ' + RTRIM(NAM)) LIKE`

Comment: @Siyual yea. thanks . It's so simple and good solution , that i did't think about it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are not alowed to use `alias name` in where clause. you have to use your expression as it is in `where clause`

```
Declare @name varchar(30) = 'Surname'  
SELECT (RTRIM(SUR) + ' ' + RTRIM(NAM)) AS name , W , SS FROM Table
WHERE (RTRIM(SUR) + ' ' + RTRIM(NAM)) like '%' + @name + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `APPLY VALUES` to achieve this as well.

It's not the best SQL design to begin with, as you won't be able to take advantage of indexing.

```
Declare @name varchar(30) = 'Joh';  //part or full name/surname or both

SELECT 
  Fullname.name AS name , 
  W , 
  SS 
FROM Table
OUTER APPLY(VALUES(RTRIM(SUR) + ' ' + RTRIM(NAM)) Fullname(name)
WHERE Fullname.name like '%' + @name + '%';
```